# How to make my laptop see my battery on Windows 8 startup

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot

So when I first boot into my computer, I can't use the system tray power icon since it doesn't think that its a laptop. So in order to get the icon enabled I go into device manager and scan for new hardware it finds "Microsoft ACPI-Complacent Control Method Battery" and then I am able to use the battery icon. Does anyone know of a way to either make my system recognize the battery on startup, or a way to automate the "scan for new hardware" function in device manager since it is a big pain to have to do that every time I boot up my laptop (Windows 8 is my backup OS, I normally run Arch and it doesn't have any problem with the battery)? Thanks

Respectfully,
Werdho

Comment: Nope once I scan for new hardware it pops up and the setting is already set like that, it only comes up when you scan for hardware, so when I boot up its not there but the second that I scan for hardware it pops up.

Comment: Try [Devcon](http://www.support.microsoft.com/kb/311272), not sure it works with win8 or not.

Comment: Another way (workaround) is to have some script autorun at startup, to send keystrokes to the device manager. Will it be fine for you ?

Comment: Yeah that would be fine with me, but what do you mean send keystrokes?

Comment: bump bump bump bump